# Implement Complex from Num

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and want to learn how to implement my Complex number from Num class.

```
data Complex = Complex{x::Float, y::Float} deriving (Show)

instance Num Complex where
        (Complex x1 y1) + (Complex x2 y2) = Complex(x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
        (Complex x1 y1) - (Complex x2 y2) = Complex(x1 - x2) (y1 - y2)
        (Complex x1 y1) * (Complex x2 y2) = Complex(x1*x2 - y1*y2) (x1*y2 + x2*y2)
        fromInteger n                     = Complex(fromInteger n) (fromInteger n) 
        signum (Complex x y)              = Complex(signum x) (signum y) 
        abs (Complex x y)                 = Complex(abs x) (abs y)
```

My question is how to use

```
fromInteger n = Complex(fromInteger n) (fromInteger n)
```

Comment: You just say @5 :: Complex@.  But your definitions of abs, signum, and fromInteger are wrong.

Comment: Note that `abs x * signum x == x` should hold for your instance.

Comment: It's also reasonable that `fromInteger (x + y) == fromInteger x + fromInteger y` (and the same for `*`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two examples of using the `fromInteger` function in GHCi:

```
λ> fromInteger 5 :: Complex
Complex {x = 5.0, y = 5.0}
```

```
λ> :set -XTypeApplications

λ> fromInteger @Complex 5
Complex {x = 5.0, y = 5.0}
```

By the way, I believe you have that implemented incorrectly. Check out [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.Complex.html#line-120) to see how it's done in `base`. It seems like it ought to be defined as:

```
fromInteger n = Complex (fromInteger n) 0
```

Comment: This is the answer that I'm looking for.  I'm very confusing how to use 'fromInteger n = Complex(fromInteger n) 0' in my actual code. Thanks for sharing.